# Can I use AWS Amplify with an independent WatchOS app?

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, watchkit

I'm building an independent WatchOS app and am trying to use AWS Amplify as the backend. However, whenever I try to install it in my Podfiles I get this error from my terminal:

```
[!] The platform of the target `xyz WatchKit App` (watchOS 6.1) is not compatible with `AmplifyPlugins/AWSAPIPlugin (0.10.0)`, which does not support `watchOS`.
```

I thought this was because I had placed it under the wrong section in the Podfile (since an independent watch has three sections (the app name, the WatchKit, and the WatchKit Extension). However, I get this response when I place the podfile info directly below the the app name:

```
 [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "amplify-tools":
 In Podfile:
amplify-tools

Specs satisfying the `amplify-tools` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I've run into this issue before, but when I change the global platform it doesn't work. Is there something I'm missing? Or is AWS not currently compatible with an independent iOS Watch app? Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [their Github page](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios#platform-support), it looks like as of version 0.10.0 there are no plans to support watchOS:

> **Platform Support**
>
> Amplify supports iOS 11 and above and iOS 13 for certain categories such as Predictions. There are currently no plans to support Amplify on WatchOS, tvOS, or MacOS.

#### Update (Jan 2023):

It looks like there are plans to support watchOS in future releases:

> **Platform Support**
>
> Amplify supports iOS 13+ and macOS 10.15+. Support for watchOS and tvOS is coming in future releases.